# Few questions on microprogrammed control (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl

[image]

I need to implement this schematic. I've already done datapath/memory/control memory.
I have no idea on how to build the part I marked in red. Can someone give me some pointers?
This is part of the assignment I have to do and I'm completely stuck on that part.

Answer (score 1):

You have a picture.  That is a good place to start.

Now write a description of what each does.  The PC for example is a register that increments following normal instructions and conditionally loads values during branch and/or jump instructions.  Fill in the details to the general description and write the code.

Do the same for each of the other blocks you have (IR, MUXC, CAR).  It is just thinking through the details.

Comment: I did try to research every bit separately, but what I need are simple, layman definitions and explanations, which is what I can't find. I don't want a solution, just some kind of explanation on what each part does.

Comment: You need a book on computer architecture.  Alternately do a search on "computer architecture mooc" - you should be able to find a free class to supplement the one you are taking.